# cleanest way to make this app for iOS

Tags: ios, search

I want to make a simple app (iOS) anyways... I want to start reading up on the proper programming language to do the following task...

User would input text into a field and that value is to be searched on a list that has 2 and up to 3 columns beside it. and display the value of that column. Should column 1 be empty it would display column 2 and 3 .

example....

```
1 a b c

2 e f g

3    h I
```

So if I type in 1 hit search it should give back A as the first answer and also say b and c as alternatives

if I type in 3 hit search it would only say h or I

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Objective-C is a must.

Comment: I recommend going to a site like http://RayWenderlich.com and reading up on basic Objective-C and iPhone app tutorials to get an idea where you need to start.

Comment: I wouldn't dive too far into pure C, a lot of bad practice going on in that language. When I first started programming I went straight for C++ because I was warned by other programmers about C. And I think obj-c is different enough from pure C that it can be learned independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic your asking about is not really language specific, but if you want to program for iOS at all I would recommend objective-c (obj-c):

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/learn-objective-c-day-1/

Once you learn how to program for the platform you can worry about how things should work in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  Will start reading it today!   I imagined it wasn't language specific just wanted to know what would be the easiest to learn to achieve that task.   have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

A place to start would be a good book on iOS development.

The native programming language for iOS is Objective-C so that is a good starting point but remember that is a layer on top of the "C" programming language so an understanding of "C" is a pre-resiquite.

There are also some tutorial sites online that are good, see other comments and answers here.

The best way to start is small which seems like what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  I do have some very basic knowledge of programming  and just wanted to do this app for me and to prove to myself that I can.